# Filter with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, range

I want to fetch a range of date with a specific id, but my result is including other id's in it. I need help checking the query.

This is what am trying to do

Fectch all documents where **uniqueid** == 1 and
**start** range from 2016-10-11T12:00:30.000Z
                     to "2016-10-12T12:00:30.000Z"

My query and results is shown below.

**Query**

```
GET _search

{
"query": {
    "constant_score": {
       "filter": {
           "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                      "term": {
                         "uniqueid": 1
                      }
                  }
               ],
               "should": [
                  {
                    "range": {
              "start": {
                 "from": "2016-10-11T12:00:30.000Z",
                 "to": "2016-10-12T12:00:30.000Z"
              }
           }  
                  }
               ]
           }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
  {
   "took": 15,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
   "total": 5,
   "successful": 5,
   "failed": 0
  },
   "hits": {
   "total": 6,
   "max_score": 1,
   "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "cdr",
        "_type": "face",
        "_id": "AVfDCsC-vh94Tg1hrkix",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "start": "2016-10-12T12:00:30.000Z",
           "answer": "2016-10-12T12:00:25.000Z",
           "end": "2016-10-12T12:00:35.000Z",
           "duration": 50,
           "billsec": 55,
           "uniqueid": 1,
           "is_successful": true,
           "is_clicked": true
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "cdr",
        "_type": "face",
        "_id": "AVfDCucPvh94Tg1hrkiy",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "start": "2016-10-12T12:00:30.000Z",
           "answer": "2016-10-12T12:00:25.000Z",
           "end": "2016-10-12T12:00:35.000Z",
           "duration": 50,
           "billsec": 55,
           "uniqueid": 2,
           "is_successful": true,
           "is_clicked": true
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "cdr",
        "_type": "face",
        "_id": "AVfDC1G2vh94Tg1hrkiz",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "start": "2016-10-13T12:00:30.000Z",
           "answer": "2016-10-13T12:00:25.000Z",
           "end": "2016-10-13T12:00:35.000Z",
           "duration": 50,
           "billsec": 55,
           "uniqueid": 2,
           "is_successful": true,
           "is_clicked": true
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "cdr",
        "_type": "face",
        "_id": "AVfDC2IGvh94Tg1hrki0",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "start": "2016-10-13T12:00:30.000Z",
           "answer": "2016-10-13T12:00:25.000Z",
           "end": "2016-10-13T12:00:35.000Z",
           "duration": 50,
           "billsec": 55,
           "uniqueid": 1,
           "is_successful": true,
           "is_clicked": true
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "cdr",
        "_type": "face",
        "_id": "AVfDCCOOvh94Tg1hrkiv",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "start": "2016-10-10T12:00:15.000Z",
           "answer": "2016-10-10T12:00:25.000Z",
           "end": "2016-10-10T12:00:35.000Z",
           "duration": 25,
           "billsec": 25,
           "uniqueid": 1,
           "is_successful": true,
           "is_clicked": true
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "cdr",
        "_type": "face",
        "_id": "AVfDCR2Uvh94Tg1hrkiw",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "start": "2016-10-11T12:00:15.000Z",
           "answer": "2016-10-11T12:00:25.000Z",
           "end": "2016-10-11T12:00:35.000Z",
           "duration": 25,
           "billsec": 25,
           "uniqueid": 1,
           "is_successful": true,
           "is_clicked": true
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: move the `range` query into the `must` array. and also use POST instead of GET when sending a payload.

Comment: @Val I tried that, still not working

Comment: Even when using POST instead of GET?

Comment: Also remove the empty line below the URL path, that's probably your issue.

Comment: @Val Thanks i removed the space and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the empty line below the URL path

```
GET _search
                      <--- remove this line
{
"query": {
```

Like this:

```
GET _search
{
   "query": {
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Val said, moving the range into must will work.

```
 {
"query": {
    "constant_score": {
       "filter": {
           "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                        "uniqueid": 1
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                        "start": {
                            "from": "2016-10-11T12:00:30.000Z",
                            "to": "2016-10-12T12:00:30.000Z"
                        }
                    }  
                  }
               ]
           }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem was more related to the empty line, which would send an empty query (i.e. `match_all`). His original query was more or less fine regarding the constraint on `uniqueid`